# Is there a foolproof method to remove spyware from Android smartphone?

Tags: malware, mobile, android, spyware

I am owning an Android smartphone. I learnt that factory reset may not remove spyware as it might have corrupted the image being installed by factory reset. Is there a foolproof method which ensures there is no spyware left on the device?

Comment: if the concept of spyware also covers the closed baseband firmwares, the best way to make sure there is no spyware is replacing that android phone with an [OpenMoko - Neo Freerunner (GTA02)](http://bb.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/Hardware/Phones) phone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done in two easy steps:

1. [Wipe your Android phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11365/do-a-total-wipe-of-my-device).
2. Download an [official factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) and flash it.

This way you make sure you have a clean firmware from the official source.

Comment: does ROM refers to internal memory ?

Comment: @user2917687 I meant a clean firmware image. Commonly referred to as ROMs.

Comment: so is gapps not a spyware anymore? :o

Comment: @Adnan is official image not available for all android versions. mine is samsung gallaxy y , android 2.3.3. i searched using google and the link u sent but no luck.

Comment: @user2917687 I Googled `Samsung Galaxy S5360 stock` and found at least 5 working links in the first two result pages.

Comment: Note that it's important to make sure it is a stock image that will wipe the entire phone though.  Some stock ROMs are configured to leave certain partitions (such as the emulated User SD card) intact.  Additionally, they often won't wipe an actual memory card.  If the APK remains in the data folder on one of these, then it will still be around after the wipe.

Comment: @AJHenderson does apk lying on sd card mean anything ? it has to be installed right ?

Comment: @user2917687 - if the APK is in the appropriate folders it will be picked up as installed.  APKs don't really have much in the way of installation.  They basically just move to particular folders and create data folders in certain places.  Both of which can be on an SD card.  This is normally the Android folder, but sometimes it can be elsewhere as well.